# How to restart Ubuntu upgrade from command line?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, command-line

I am trying to upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04. After numerous hours, the upgrade finally hung on the replacing packages stage. It was showing 'replacing network adaptor' for more than half an hour. There was no way to get any response.

So eventually I powered off the machine. When I powered it back on, it boots into command line mode showing release 12.04. How can I restart the process from the command line?

Comment: Type sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop in terminal ,what is the output?

Comment: It returned a message saying dpkg failed and a commend to enter. I entered the stated command and the install appears to be continuing. I'll post up the end result when it's finished.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very much sure about how to restart the packages, I would advice you to download the Ubuntu image from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download) or from torrent and install it from a CD or flash drive.

12.04 has got a very good set of options to Install 'Freshly' or 'Upgrade it from 11.10'. This way it would be a lot more stabler without any interruptions and moreover it will be quick.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the command:

```
kill
```

For more information, run:

```
man kill
```

Comment: Can you please explain how it works :)